# ColdFusion - Trying to store client variables in registry even though set to Cookie?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

My ColdFusion instance is throwing the following error in the coldfusion-out.log file.

> Mar 16, 2019 23:59:58 PM Information [ajp-bio-8013-exec-1] - Unable to
>   set value
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\ColdFusion\CurrentVersion\Clients\6037671-54317b2e75ffe265-6210232F-5056-9D86-AFD90AADCC13ABBD[VARIABLE_NAME_HERE]:
>   Windows error number 0 occurred.The handle is invalid.

All the searching I've done this morning points to this being caused by ColdFusion set to store Client Variables in the Registry, however I've checked and double checked and mine is set to store in Cookie.

Is there any OTHER reason this error would be getting triggered?  It seems to have started about 3 days ago.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you use ColdFusion Enterprise? Have you modified your setting on the correct instance?

Comment: Where did you check for the setting? I believe it can be set in the CF Administrator and/or in any Application.cfc file.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler - yes I do and I am modifying the correct instance.

Comment: @Miguel-F - I'm modifying it within the cfide, not the Application.cfc.

Comment: Even though the CFIDE shows I'm using Cookies for Client Variables, clicking on Edit on the Registry option gave me a checkbox for Disable global client variable updates.  When I checked that, the error has stopped.  Not sure why that would matter though since it wasn't even using Registry for variables.

Comment: Why do you want to store client variables in cookies? Cookies are extremely limited in size... could you be exceeding how much data can be stored with cookies? Either way, I would at least store client variables in a cache.